# C++ Setters not assigning values to derivative classes

Tags: c++, getter-setter, derived-class

My setters are not setting. I've worked this problem on an off for about a week and a half now. It's like everything falls into place, code compiles and seems like everything is working hunky-dory, but my setters are not setting, even after correctly instantiating two different objects from the derivatives:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h> // _getch()
#include <string>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

#define TMSG_LEN_PRICE 0.02 // Price of Text Message


// 1st Derived Class, Text Message
class tMsg
{
private:
    float textMessageInCharacters;
public:
    tMsg() {
        textMessageInCharacters = 0.0f;
    }
    // Getter
    int getTextMessageLength()
    {
        return textMessageInCharacters;
    }

    // Setter
    void setTextMessageLength(int textLength)
    {
        textMessageInCharacters = textLength;
    }
};

int main()
{
    string usrInput;   // User Input
    string tMessage; // Text message string
    int vMessage_Min;    // Voice message length in minutes

    try
    {

        tMsg textService; // Text messaging service

        // Menu output for user.
        printf("Select an option:\n\nT. Text Message\nV. Voice Message\n\nOption: ");
        getline(cin, usrInput);

        // Get text message from user
        if (usrInput == "t") {
            printf("Input your message then hit [ENTER] when done: \nMessage: ");
            getline(cin, tMessage);
            textService.setTextMessageLength(tMessage.size());

        }
    }

    // Catch exception
    catch (exception& ex) {
        // Throw exception
        cout << ex.what();

        // Pause screen wait for user input
        _getch();
    }

    // Exit
    return 0;

}
```

It doesn't really create an output and when I BREAK on certain assignments within the derived classes, the program terminates as if nothing is being assigned. I ensure that the local variables are taking in the assigned values, but something with the instantiation it does not like.

Edit: Shortened Uneccessary Code needed.

Comment: You can shorten this down to make a [mcve] by removing all the functions you're not using in the example program, like `getMessagePrice`, `getTextMessageLength`, `getVoiceMessageLength`, `setMessagePrice` and `setVoiceMessageLength`. It looks like the only setter you _do_ use is `setTextMessageLength`.

Comment: The reason nothing is assigned is because you never call any of the setters.

Comment: What part of the code is supposed to create any output? You never try to print out the values of any members.

Comment: why create an instance of your base class instead of the voice class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Getter Setter were working. You were not calling getter in main. Hope it will help you!**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h> // _getch()
#include <string>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

#define VMSG_LEN_PRICE 0.03 // Price of Voice Message
#define TMSG_LEN_PRICE 0.02 // Price of Text Message

// Base Class
class qMsg
{
private:
    float messagePrice; // Final Return Price of Messages Voice/Text
public:
    qMsg() {
        messagePrice = 0.0f;
    }

    // Getter
    int getMessagePrice()
    {
        return messagePrice;
    }

    // Setter
    void setMessagePrice(float price)
    {
        messagePrice = price;
    }
};

// 1st Derived Class, Text Message
class tMsg : public qMsg
{
private:
    float textMessageInCharacters;
public:
    tMsg() {
        textMessageInCharacters = 0.0f;

    }

    // Setter
    void setTextMessageLength(int textLength)
    {
        textMessageInCharacters = textLength;

    }
    // Getter
    int getTextMessageLength()
    {
        return textMessageInCharacters;
    }

};

// 2nd Derived Class, Voice Message
class vMsg : public qMsg
{
private:
    float voiceMessageInMinutes;
public:
    vMsg() {
        voiceMessageInMinutes = 0.0f;
    }
    // Getter
    int getVoiceMessageLength()
    {
        return voiceMessageInMinutes;
    }

    // Setter
    void setVoiceMessageLength(int voiceLength)
    {
        voiceMessageInMinutes = voiceLength;
    }

};

int main()
{
    string usrInput;   // User Input
    string tMessage; // Text message string
    int vMessage_Min;    // Voice message length in minutes

    try
    {
        qMsg commServices; // Voice messaging service
        tMsg textService; // Text messaging service

                          // Menu output for user.
        printf("Select an option:\n\nT. Text Message\nV. Voice Message\n\nOption: ");
        getline(cin, usrInput);

        // Get text message from user
        if (usrInput == "t") {
            printf("Input your message then hit [ENTER] when done: \nMessage: ");
            getline(cin, tMessage);
            textService.setTextMessageLength(tMessage.size());
            cout << "GET MESSAGE LENGTH :  ";
            cout<<textService.getTextMessageLength();
            cout << endl;        


        }
        else if (usrInput == "v")
        {
            // Return minutes for voice message
            printf("Input the length of your voice message: ");
            cin >> vMessage_Min;

        }

    }

    // Catch exception
    catch (exception& ex) {
        // Throw exception
        cout << ex.what();

        // Pause screen wait for user input
        _getch();
    }

    // Exit
    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Thank you, I just didn't know why my code wasn't breaking when I set my breakpoint. It didn't occur to me to call my getter for debugging =\.